# PowerPoint vba group shapes using Shape objects, not shape names

Tags: vba, grouping, powerpoint, shapes

I've written some code that formats text. The code doesn't work if user has put the cursor in a shape that is part of a group of shapes, the solution for which is to ungroup the shapes.

I want to regroup the shapes after executing the formatting code.

I am able to store the underlying shapes as objects, as well as their names. But, the normal approach to grouping (using shape names) doesn't work, because there can be multiple instances of those shape names on a given slide. E.g. this doesn't work as there could be multiple instances of "textbox" on the slide:

```
Set TempShapeGroup = TempSlide.Shapes.Range(Array("textbox", "header", "separator")).Group
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shaperange.group

But, I have the shape objects stored in an array, the crux of which is this (the object 'TempShape' is the group of shapes):

```
Dim ShapesArray()               As Shape
ReDim ShapesArray(1 To TempShape.GroupItems.Count)

For i = 1 To TempShape.GroupItems.Count
    Set ShapesArray(i) = TempShape.GroupItems.Item(i)
Next i
```

So, what I want to do is recreate the group of shapes, using the array of shape objects, so something to the effect of the below would be ideal:

```
Set MyShapesGroup= ShapesArray.Group
```

But any way to group shapes using Shape objects would be fine.

TIA

Comment: Btw I have tried the last section of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965794/how-to-group-each-shape-in-a-selection-of-a-powerpoint-slide-using-vba

But same issue arises with having multiple shapes with same name on the slide, hence the need to use the objects, not their names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some starter code that you can modify into a function that'll return a reference to the paragraph that contains the current selection cursor.  It doesn't really need all the debug.print stuff, of course, but that might help to illustrate the object hierarchy:

```
Sub WhereIsTheCursor()

Dim oRng As TextRange
Dim oParentRange As TextRange
Dim x As Long
Dim lSelStart As Long
Dim lSelLen As Long

With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
    ' find the selection start relative to first character in shape
    lSelStart = .Start
'    lSelLen = .Length
    
    Debug.Print TypeName(.Parent)
    Debug.Print TypeName(.Parent.Parent)
    Debug.Print TypeName(.Parent.Parent.Parent)
    Debug.Print .Paragraphs.Count
    Set oRng = .Characters(.Start, .Length)
    Debug.Print oRng.Text
    
    ' Reference the overall shape's textrange
    Set oParentRange = .Parent.Parent.TextFrame.TextRange
    
    ' For each paragraph in the range ...
    For x = 1 To oParentRange.Paragraphs.Count
    
        ' is the start of the selection > the start of the paragraph?
        If lSelStart > oParentRange.Paragraphs(x).Start Then
            ' is the start < the start + length of the paragraph?
            If lSelStart < oParentRange.Paragraphs(x).Start _
               + oParentRange.Paragraphs(x).Length Then
               ' bingo!
               MsgBox "The cursor is in paragraph " & CStr(x)
            End If
        End If
    
    Next
    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Took a couple of hours to adapt it, but that is indeed the answer I've been looking for for so long. 
Can't thank you enough Steve!!!!! :-D Wish I could send you a bottle of whiskey!

Comment: @JakeyG Oh, so do I, so do I.  I'm a devout equal-opportunity whiskey fan. Bourbon, Irish, all good!  Best, though, is single-malt Scotch. The smokier/peatier the bettier. ;-)  But your thanks is ample pay.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm completely understanding the problem, but this may help:

If the user has selected text within a shape, it doesn't really matter whether the shape is part of a group or not.  You may need to test the .Selection.Type and handle things differently depending on whether the .Type is text or shaperange. Example:

```
Sub FormatCurrentText()

If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionText Then

    With ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange
        .Font.Name = "Algerian"
    End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Not quite that simple - it involves also setting tab stops at paragraph level so need to interact with cursor position in the shape, not just the shape overall

Comment: @JakeyG Nothing's ever simple. Sigh. ;-)  By "cursor position in the shape", do you mean index (ie, 8th character in), or a measurement in inches/cm from the edge of the shape/edge of the slide? That would be tricky, as PPT doesn't return that info via the OM. If there's a text selection (as opposed to just text cursor w/in some text), ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.BoundLeft will give you the leftmost position of the selected text (in points from the left side of the slide).  It'll error if the cursor's just sitting w/in the text but w/o text selected.  Maybe this'll help.

Comment: @JakeyG By the way, it's unusual for multiple shapes on one slide to have the same name; normally PPT prohibits it, but sometimes IT creates them. A bug. Sounds like something's a bit amiss in the presentation, but sometimes we didn't make the mess, we just have to cope with it.

Comment: Shapes being the same name due to custom groups of shapes added via a custom toolbar, not a built-in thing.
By 'cursor position', I mean say I want to set a custom bullet level and type for only the line the cursor is on, rather than all rows in the shape. But that's a bit of a digression from the main question anyway.